# Превышен лимит выполнения

Tags: c++

И так я пишу програмулину, которую будет проверять компуктер, и проблема в том что на моей локальной машине все работает в штатном режиме, но при загрузке в систему на все тесты у меня выходит `Time limit exception`. Прикрепляю само задание и свой код. (И да считывать посимвольно это задание).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что строка обязательно заканчивается `\n`?

Comment: Формат ввода данных - Ряд символов заканчивающийся СИМВОЛОМ ПЕРЕНОСА СТРОКИ. ))

Comment: А, да, не обратил внимания... А если строка пустая, что будет? Один только `\n` и **дальше - ничего**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формальный ответ:

Ваш код не работает, если входная строка - пустая, т.е. если **весь** ввод представляет собой только одно `\n`.

Впрочем, я бы действовал так:

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);
int result = 0;
for(auto c: s)
    if (isdigit(c)) ++result;
cout << result << endl;
```

Comment: Дело в том что Time limit происходит при любом тесте, даже когда вводится нормальная строка... (У меня есть список тестов не пройденных)

Comment: [Списко тестов](https://imgur.com/a/pULhOuE)

Comment: URL не дадите? Войти и посмотреть?

Comment: К сожалению вас без аккаунта не пустит, это Яндексовская МШП, в нее надо поступить чтобы получить задание...

Comment: Ну попробуйте мой вариант...

Comment: Через строку то понятно, но мы "типо" не проходили их, я то их знаю, но лучше их не использовать))

Comment: `int result = 0;
    for(char c; (c = cin.get()) != '\n'; )
        if (isdigit(c)) result++;
    cout << result << endl;` Уже даже интересно... а так?

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря идее Harry у меня вышло что-то такое:

```
int result = 0;

for(char i = cin.get(); i!='\n'; i = cin.get()){
    if(isdigit(i)){
        result++;
    }
}

cout<<result;
return 0;
```